# Is it possible to make a selection tool for an ImageIcon in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to select part of an image in an ImageIcon on JLabel and fill it with color.
Is this possible I have become a little confused as I have read that an ImageIcon is not selectable but I am not sure if that means I have to find another way of displaying the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, yes, difficult, yes.

You need to start with a `BufferedImage`, which you can then wrap in a `ImageIcon` and apply to a `JLabel`.

You would then need to register a `MouseMotionListener` and `MouseListener` to the label to detect the area which was selected, you would then modify the `BufferedImage` accordingly and repaint everything.

Having said that, I wouldn't use a `JLabel`, as you can't accurately calculate the location that the label renders the icon, instead, I'd make myself a custom component, extending from `JPanel` and encapsulate the functionality within it and use custom painting to paint the image (and the selection area)

Start by having a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and possibly [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)